# Finding one's closed question

Tags: support, closed-questions

I asked a question on Stack Overflow and got some interesting feedback on it. I went back to it today and it has disappeared - there were some votes to close it previously so I presume it was closed.

Where would I find closed questions that I wrote on Stack Overflow?

Comment: If you are asking a question, and you find yourself typing the word "best"... Stop writing the question and close the tab.

Answer (score 6):

Searching for [user:me closed:1 is:question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+closed%3A1+is%3Aquestion&submit=search) will bring up a list of your closed questions.

Alternatively, you can check out all your questions on [your profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/373674/amateur?tab=questions&sort=newest).

Answer (score 1):

If you can't see it it means it was deleted, not just closed.

Only moderator can see deleted questions in your profile, so assuming one will appear here at some point you can ask him/her to take a look.

Otherwise unless you kept bookmark of the question (or its ID) I fear there's nothing you can do.

Comment: Cant find it in the closed list so yes it must have been deleted - how can I go about getting it "undeleted"?

Comment: Only by asking a moderator - but many chances he will refuse. Usually when something is deleted it's with a reason and for the best interest of the community.